# How to properly copy-paste a slide with Apache POI

Tags: apache-poi

I'm trying to duplicate a slide in Apache POI.

Depending on the slide content I have three cases

1. The duplication succeeds (also for some slides with XSLFPictureShape objects)
2. I get NullPointerException while POI is trying to copy a XSLFPictureShape (stacktrace follows)

   Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
       at org.apache.poi.xslf.usermodel.XSLFSheet.importBlip(XSLFSheet.java:651)
       at org.apache.poi.xslf.usermodel.XSLFPictureShape.copy(XSLFPictureShape.java:202)
       at org.apache.poi.xslf.usermodel.XSLFSheet.wipeAndReinitialize(XSLFSheet.java:452)
       at org.apache.poi.xslf.usermodel.XSLFSheet.importContent(XSLFSheet.java:431)
       at org.apache.poi.xslf.usermodel.XSLFSlide.importContent(XSLFSlide.java:294)
   ...
3. I get ClassCastException while POI is trying to copy a XSLFPictureShape (stacktrace follows)

   Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.poi.ooxml.POIXMLDocumentPart cannot be cast to org.apache.poi.xslf.usermodel.XSLFPictureData
       at org.apache.poi.xslf.usermodel.XSLFSheet.importBlip(XSLFSheet.java:651)
       at org.apache.poi.xslf.usermodel.XSLFPictureShape.copy(XSLFPictureShape.java:223)
       at org.apache.poi.xslf.usermodel.XSLFSheet.wipeAndReinitialize(XSLFSheet.java:452)
       at org.apache.poi.xslf.usermodel.XSLFSheet.importContent(XSLFSheet.java:431)
       at org.apache.poi.xslf.usermodel.XSLFSlide.importContent(XSLFSlide.java:294)
   ...

What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE**

I have found that the NullPointerException issue of point #2 was due to a corrupted pptx file (maybe because it has been edited once with a mac?)

The only real issue I have now is the one at point #3

**UPDATE**

It seems that ClassCastException of point #3 was due to some pictures with "artistic effects" applied on them, that are currently unsupported by Apache POI. Copying the pictures in PowerPoint and pasting "as image" removes the effect and the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the asnwer my own as stated in the updates of the original questions:

I have found that the NullPointerException issue of point #2 was due to a corrupted pptx file (maybe because it has been edited once with a mac?)

It seems that ClassCastException of point #3 was due to some pictures with "artistic effects" applied on them, that are currently unsupported by Apache POI. Copying the pictures in PowerPoint and pasting "as image" removes the effect and the issue.